# CPU spikes observed when jruby tries to connect to database through jdbc/mysql driver

Tags: jruby, cpu-usage

I am running a simple JRuby program which will fetch 2000 records from table using a jdbc/mysql driver.I am running the program on 3 core Ubuntu machine and with 4GB memory.
The database on same machine. When I try to execute the following program , I observe huge CPU spikes.

For the first few iterations CPU spikes between 150% to 200% and then gradually it comes down.I am using JRuby 1.7.3 for this and a oracle jdk6 
Program:

```
require 'java'
require 'rubygems'
require 'jdbc/mysql'
Jdbc::MySQL.load_driver
module JavaLang
 include_package "java.lang"
end
module JavaSql
 include_package 'java.sql'
end
begin
 loop do
  com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.new
  conn = JavaSql::DriverManager
  .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db_name","root","password");
  stmt = conn.createStatement

  resultSet = stmt.executeQuery("select * from properties limit 2000")
 end

 resultSet.close
 stmt.close
 conn.close()
end

rescue JavaLang::ClassNotFoundException
 puts "ClassNotFoundException"
rescue JavaSql::SQLException
 puts "SQLException"
end
```

I have also tried to run similar code with ruby and mysql2 adapter and observed low CPU spike. Following is the ruby program

```
require 'mysql2'

client = Mysql2::Client.new(
 host: "localhost", 
 username: "root",
 password: "password",
 database: "db_name",
)
loop do
 results = client.query("SELECT * FROM properties limit 2000")

 records = results.map do |row|
 row
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting Xms and Xmx values to some max limit